# Enabling/Disabling Button based on the validation of the text box is not working

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF user control containing the textbox and the button.
The textbox has the validation rule associated(which executes some business rule. This class implements ValidationRule).
The button needs to be enabled/disabled based on the textbox validation result.

The validation of the textbox is happening properly.

The enabled/disabling of the button is not happening properly.
Once the button gets enabled, it does not get disabled even if the validation of the textbox results in 
error.

```
      <TextBox MaxLength="3" Width="40" Margin="5" x:Name="Text1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Densities[0].Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <administration:ValidateDensityRule/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
```

Button Xaml

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text1,Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>                                    
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: You missed **ElementName** in your DataTrigger Binding. Change your DataTrigger to `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Text1,Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide `ElementName` to your binding so that it can be binded properly to your TextBox -

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=Text1}" 
             Value="True">
```

Right now you can see binding error in your output window.